# GET "www.example.com" is taking 2s in the waterfall on GTmatrix , is there any way i can reduce that?

Tags: wordpress

I Tried GTmatrix and web page test 
the first request does take a lot of time I never it below Time to First Byte: 3247 ms, I am using WordPress with the minimum plugin, and very simple homepage, I guess this is because of some server issue,

Answer (score 0):

You could use any CDN service to cache the static content of your website. The easiest and one of the best CDN available is [cloudflare.com](http://cloudflare.com)
and the best thing about cloudflare is it's FREE!!

Comment: i am using cludflare , and have caching enable and everything else is good, even the score on google page speed are 90+ , but TTFB is still same, it is the lowest of 3s,

Comment: then check your internet speed may be?